# Poner una NavBar en todas mis paginas Html

Tags: html, css

quiero poner mi NavBar en todas mis paginas HTML, pero no encuentro la forma de integrarla, hay alguna manera? o tengo que copiar y pegar el código cada vez?
intente por medio de Iframe, pero creo que no va a funcionar la superposicion de los elementos desplegables del SubMenu de la NavBar, ocupo ayuda, soy muy principiante, por lo que no he tocado nada de PHP y muy poco de JS.
Adjunto el Codigo de la Nav bar, la cual ya tiene sus estilos CSS

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Escuderia Fenix</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/Barra.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="navbg">
        <a href="bienvenida.html">
          <img src="../image/Fenix_Logo.png" class="logo" alt="Logo">
        </a>
        <nav class="Baner-Principal">
          <ul class="Baner-Principal">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Nosotros</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">wadwq</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">dadsda</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">dsadad</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Patrocinadores</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">etddgfg</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">rdgfd</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">grdgd</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="integrantes.html">Integrantes</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sadd</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">gdrgf</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">bfdb4we</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Contacto</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">gdfgr</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">y,iuh</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">jghrj5tr</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar fragmentos de HTML de un archivo externo e incluirlos en el resto de páginas que quieras utilizando la etiqueta `<object>`, primero crea el archivo que contendrá el fragmento sin body ni head (el navbar en tu caso) con algun nombre como *navbar-template.html* por ejemplo, quedaria asi:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="navbg">
        <a href="bienvenida.html">
          <img src="../image/Fenix_Logo.png" class="logo" alt="Logo">
        </a>
        <nav class="Baner-Principal">
          <ul class="Baner-Principal">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Nosotros</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">wadwq</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">dadsda</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">dsadad</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Patrocinadores</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">etddgfg</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">rdgfd</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">grdgd</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="integrantes.html">Integrantes</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sadd</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">gdrgf</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">bfdb4we</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Contacto</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">gdfgr</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">y,iuh</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">jghrj5tr</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Luego, para incluir ese fragmento en tu página principal o en cualquier página que quieras haces lo siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <object data="navbar-template.html" 
          type="text/html" 
          style="height: 500px; width: 100%;">
  </object>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <h1>World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Coloque el navbar al principio del body porque asumí que estaba en esa posición pero tú puedes agregar otras etiquetas al principio o al final. Despues existen los motores de plantillas como Mustache.js pero no quise complicarte la vida. Documentacion de [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object). Asegurate de colocar bien la ruta del archivo en la propiedad 'data'.

**EDIT**: viendo los inconvenientes que presentaba mi solución al leer la respuesta de @Yussef, pude averiguar que para aplicar estilos al fragmento debemos utilizar si o si las etiquetas html, head y body al mismo. Edite mi respuesta para que funcionara aplicando estilos personalizados al navbar.

Answer (score 1):

Usando [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Web_Components), es posible crear un componente personalizado que te permita hacer lo que buscas. La diferencia de este Script con usar `object`, es que de esta manera se aplicará el CSS al contenido externo

1.- Copias este script y lo colocas junto con el resto de tus scripts

```
customElements.define('yus-html',
  class extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
          super();
      }
      connectedCallback() {
          fetch(this.getAttribute("src"))
              .then(r => r.text())
              .then(t => {
                  let parser = new DOMParser();
                  let html = parser.parseFromString(t, "text/html");
                  this.innerHTML = html.body.innerHTML;
              }).catch(e => console.error(e));

      }
});
```

2.- Creas tu menú u otros HTML que deseas repetir, solo lo interno (sin usar las etiquetas HTML, BODY y HEAD)

```
<header>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="navbg">
        <a href="bienvenida.html">
          <img src="../image/Fenix_Logo.png" class="logo" alt="Logo">
        </a>
        <nav class="Baner-Principal">
         
          <!-- ETC !-->
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

3.- Luego para usarlo solo debes hacer:

```
<body>
    <yus-html src="Menu.html"></yus-html>
    <div class="row">
        <yus-html src="OtroHtml.html"></yus-html>
    </div>

    <yus-html src="OtroOtroHtml.html"></yus-html>

</body>
```

*(Puedes usarlo para distintos HTML, las veces que quieras)*